# Session not found - Session Cache not supported

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob

In my async apex future method, I am getting an error "Session not found - Session Cache not supported". An apex class called by the future method is accessing the session cache. This should work, it was working prior to me installing Spring 21 release. I have a potential workaround which is to not access session in future context.

Anyone know why Salesforce would disable session cache in async context in Spring 21?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Session.htm#!) session cache is not available in async as you have found. This is newly added in API version 51 (Spring 21) and is not mentioned in version 50 (Winter 21). Another case of tightened security perhaps?

Comment: I stopped using Session cache in async apex. Issue is resolved. You are right about the security tightening part; seems logical for Salesforce to close this loophole.